# contradicting identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

the identity theorem for holomorphic functions states: given functions $f$ and $g$ holomorphic on a connected open set $D$, if $f = g$ on some open subset of $D$, then $f = g$ on $D$

Let $f(z) = \sin z + \cos z$, 
    $g(z) = \cos z$

then $(f-g)(0) = 0$
$\implies$ by the above theorem : $f(z) = g(z)$ on $\left|z\right|<1$
$\implies$ $\sin z + \cos z = \cos z$
$\implies \sin z =$ identically zero in $\left|z\right|<1$ which is not true

Where could I be making a mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conclude that $f=g$ on $D$, you must show that $f=g$ on some *open* subset of $D$. You did not show that, you just noticed that $f(0)=g(0)$, but $\{0\}$ is not an open subset of $D$.

Answer (score 2):

These two functions must coïncide on an open subset. In your reasoning you use only one point, which is not an open subset.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that .